# getting data from checkbox and put in the database using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

Whenever i select multiple checkbox to save in the database it shows error and when i didn't select any box just write the groupname, it save the name in database.

GroupDetail.java

```
package com.userauthenticate.model;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
@Entity
public class GroupDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String groupName;
@ManyToMany
private Set<UserDetail> user= new HashSet<UserDetail>();
@OneToMany
private Set<Role> role= new HashSet<Role>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public Set<UserDetail> getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Set<UserDetail> user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Set<Role> getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Set<Role> role) {
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

GroupController.java

```
package com.userauthenticate.controller;

import com.userauthenticate.model.GroupDetail;
import com.userauthenticate.service.GroupDetailService;
import com.userauthenticate.service.RoleService;
import com.userauthenticate.service.UserDetailService;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class GroupController {

  @Autowired
  private GroupDetailService groupDetailService;

  @Autowired
  private RoleService roleService;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailService userDetailService;

  private String msg = "namme in group";

  @RequestMapping("grouplist")
  public ModelAndView grouplist() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("grouplists");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", msg);
    modelAndView.addObject("grouplist", groupDetailService.getGrouplist());
    modelAndView.addObject("rolelist", roleService.getRolelist());
    modelAndView.addObject("userlist", userDetailService.getUserList());
    modelAndView.addObject("group", new GroupDetail());
    return modelAndView;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/addgroup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView addgroup(@ModelAttribute("group") GroupDetail group) {
    //        System.out.println(333);
    System.out.println(group.getGroupName());
    groupDetailService.add(group);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/grouplist");
  }


}
```

Grouplists.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" 
    uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO- 
   8859-1" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome, ${message}</h1> <a href="/">LogOut</a>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <form:form action="/addgroup" method="post" modelAttribute="group">
        <tr>
            <td>Group Name</td>
            <td><form:input type="text" name="eee" path="groupName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>
                <%--<form:checkboxes path="role" items="${rolelist}" itemValue="${rolelist.id}"/>--%>
                <c:forEach items="${rolelist}" var="r">
                    <form:checkbox value="${r.id}" path="role"/> ${r.role}
                </c:forEach>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Users</td>
            <td>
                <c:forEach items="${userlist}" var="u">
                    <form:checkbox value="${u.email}" path="user"/> ${u.name}(${u.email})
                </c:forEach>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form:form>
    </tbody>
</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> 400- Bad Request The server cannot or will not process the request due
>   to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox you tick will take value and put it in array of value.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addgroup",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addgroup(@RequestParam("role") int[] roleid, @RequestParam("groupName") String groupname, @RequestParam("user") String[] email){
    if (!groupname.equals(""))
        groupDetailService.add(roleid,groupname,email);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/grouplist");
}
```